# Access denied for user 'user'@'host.localdomain'

Tags: mysql

We have three Servers in our lab. The host names of these servers are:
`A`, `B` and `C` say.

Three of them have `MySQL` installed and is working fine.

The issue is:

When I am trying to connect to the `MySQL` server on machine `B` from `A` using:

```
mysql -u username -h 10.0.0.230 -p
```

I am getting an error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user'@'B.localdomain'
```

The  `/etc/hosts` file of `A` looks like:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       A
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

And the `/etc/hosts` file of `B` looks like:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost B.localdomain
10.0.0.230  A.localdomain
10.0.0.232  C.localdomain
```

The user `testadmin` exists in the `MySQL` database in `B`.

Any reasons for this kind of error? Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to grant rights for your user `'user'@'B.localdomain'` see also [documentation for](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant.html)

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your server binding address in order to connect on an address rather than the local one (*localhost*).

So, e.g. for your machine B, under */etc/mysql/my.cnf*, change ***bind-adrdess*** property to "10.0.0.231" as follows (assuming that 10.0.0.231 is ip address of B):

```
bind-address        = 10.0.0.231
```

Then grant the *testadmin* user the needed privileges to access the *mysql* server under machine B:

```
mysql> GRANT ALL ON `database_name`.* TO 'testadmin'@'A.localdoamin' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

You can follow the same schema for A and C.